# ReportViewer Error When AsyncRendering set to false

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I have problem using reportviewer with asyncrendering set to false, the report showing this error message:
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host", this report is running on iis 7 and windows 7 on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno what configuration i did wrong but when i change from "http://localhost" on serverurl property into http://[ip address] everything runs ok.